# How should I set up a flash bracket for Pentax?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, flash, off-camera-flash, pentax, flash-bracket

I have a Pentax K-r and a Metz mecablitz 50 AF-1 digital flash unit, and I've been having problems with red-eye.  As a result, I'm considering getting a flash bracket.

I am aware that I can simply buy the [bracket itself](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/278249-REG/Manfrotto_233B_233B_Telescoping_Camera_Flash_Bracket.html) (and the [required cold shoe part](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/89989-REG/Hama_HA_6959_Accessory_Shoe_1_4_20_Bottom.html) or [Pentax Off-Camera Shoe Adapter F](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/112755-REG/Pentax_31046_Off_Camera_Shoe_Adpater.html)), and use the pop-up flash as a master or controller in a wireless P-TTL setup.  However, I am aware that I will lose aperture, ISO, and focal length communication (required for auto zoom) with the flash as well as high-speed sync and possibly rear-curtain sync.  The flash should still be able to sync correctly and the camera should be able to meter properly.  (I've done off-camera flash before, but I don't like Strobist.)  Under what circumstances would this be acceptable?

I am aware that are [certain Pentax accessories](http://www.pentaximaging.com/accessories/#anchor11) that appears to allow P-TTL communication with the camera and enable full functionality.  If I get the following accessories:

- [Pentax Hot Shoe Adapter F](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/41177-REG/Pentax_31022_Hot_Shoe_Adapter_F.html)
- [Pentax Off-Camera Shoe Adapter F](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/112755-REG/Pentax_31046_Off_Camera_Shoe_Adpater.html)
- [Pentax Short Extension Cord F5P](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/41049-REG/Pentax_37347_F5P_3_Extension_Cord.html)

will I indeed get full P-TTL functionality, with aperture and ISO communication as well as high-speed sync and rear-curtain sync?  Will the flash be able to zoom automatically with these parts?  If so, is this worth the extra money?  How useful is this extra functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used those accessories, but that's exactly what they seem to be designed for.

Avoiding direct light on optical axis in favor of bounced or further off-camera flash (triggered optically or with the longer cord, haven't yet seen any [P-TTL capable radio triggers](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16210/are-there-any-radio-flash-triggers-capable-of-p-ttl)) might give you more pleasing results. For these cases, you'll probably want to take manual control over flash zoom. Unfortunately Metz flashes are quite stubborn to turn the Auto Zoom back on after a while.

But, as you say in your comments, bouncing is not always feasible and setting up off-camera flash or using red eye reduction takes too much time for live action. In such situations, I have simulated the telescoping bracket by shooting with one hand and holding the flash out in left hand, but it's too easy to tilt camera this way, so having the bracket seems tempting.

Comment: The problem is that bounce flash is not always an option.  I would use it if this was possible, but I often don't have a usable surface to bounce the flash from.  I don't do studio shooting - I'm shooting events where I cannot make complex lighting setups.

Comment: @DragonLord In that case... Have you already tried turning on red-eye reduction, or diffusing your light?

Comment: Diffusing doesn't work for me.  I haven't used red-eye reduction much, so I'm not sure if this helps, and this introduces a significant delay before the shutter is released.

Comment: @DragonLord oh gosh, I now noticed the holding distance range provided by the bracket. It certainly changed my opinion, updated my answer.

Comment: So is the P-TTL functionality provided by the wired connection and shoe adapters worth the extra cost?  What situations would make this functionality useful or necessary?

Comment: @DragonLord - Are you planning on moving around so much that the distance is going to substantially change? If not, then manual setting of the flash may actually not be much of an issue. That's really the question to answer before deciding if the accessories would be of value to you.