# Are there any radio flash triggers capable of P-TTL?

Tags: off-camera-flash, pentax, wireless-triggers, ttl

All the popular radio TTL flash triggers, like PocketWizard or RadioPopper, seem to be only available in Nikon and Canon flavors. Are there any models capable of transmitting Pentax P-TTL data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.aokatec.com/

This radio trigger appears to support P-TTL and high-speed sync.

I found this in this dpreview forum thread: http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1036&message=40799541&changemode=1

See also http://www.lightingrumours.com/aokatec-ttl-trigger-for-nikon-canon-sony-pentax-1875.

Comment: New product! Cool!

Comment: I'd be happy to accept this answer, but the product is still "available soon". Oh well, let's wait some more...

Comment: I have a sample and will test it out this weekend.

Comment: [A review](http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/pentax-flashes-lighting-technique/195068-aokatec-ak-ttl-radio-wireless-ttl-flash-trigger-nikon-canon-pentax-sony.html) reveals it's a clever solution converting optical commands into radio signal and then back to optical.

Answer (score 4):

The following radio-based flash triggering systems can communicate TTL for Pentax:

- The [Cactus X-TTL system](https://www.cactus-image.com/special/X-TTL/) with their V6II/IIs triggers can give you remote power control over TTL Pentax flashes, HSS sympathy triggering, and full TTL passthrough to an on-camera flash mounted on top of the trigger, as well as P-TTL with remote flashes.
- [Phottix's Odin II](https://www.phottixus.com/products/flash-triggers/odin-ii/phottix-odin-ii-ttl-flash-trigger-transmitter-for-pentax.html) triggers.
- Godox has [XPro-P](http://www.godox.com/EN/Products_Remote_Control_XproP_TTL_Wireless_Flash_Trigger.html) and [X2T-P](http://flashhavoc.com/flashpoint-r2-t-mark-ii-godox-x2t-transmitter-released/) transmitters that offer P-TTL and HSS compatibility with the Godox X system. At this time (Nov 2019) however, the AD360II cannot be used in P-TTL/HSS off-camera, and the TT685C is the only TT685 model that can be firmware upgraded for off-camera P-TTL. The only P-TTL speedlights in the Godox lineup are the TT350-P and V1-P.
- The [Aokatec](http://www.aokatec.com/) AK-TTL works something like a poor man's RadioPopper—it takes the light signals used by Pentax's wireless flash system and turns them into radio signals then translates back out the other end.
- The [Acon R930](http://acon-tech.com/?page_id=24) seems to be using the hotshoe protocol to communicate TTL, since it uses all the pins/contacts on the flash hotshoe, but bridged over radio, but doesn't look widely available.
- The [Conanmark ABC](http://flashhavoc.com/cononmark-abc-transmitter-for-fuji-pentax-announced/) TTL radio triggers have a Pentax version, but it doesn't look like it's widely available.